# Working With Unix Domain Sockets In Python - How to possibly loop through lines coming from socket and perform actions on those lines?

Tags: python, sockets, unix, unix-socket, tcpsocket

Essentially I started using sockets because of how fast and efficient they are.  Basically I have a program in python that parses the lines coming from the sockets but this program works on a .txt file. I'm trying to figure out a way to incorporate my program but using it on the sockets. The code is below.

```
#!/bin/python

import socket
import os, os.path

if os.path.exists("/home/log/socket"):
  os.remove("/home/log/socket")

log = socket.socket(socket.AF_UNIX, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
log.bind("/home/log/socket")

while True:
  print(log.recv(4096))
```

This is what I'm using to receive the socket. My main concern is I have to parse the data I'm getting from the socket before I upload it to my DB.

Here is my python parse program.

```
import threading

def text_org():   #fuction, if you want to run this, make sure you call the fuction!
    threading.Timer(300.0, text_org).start()


    infile = open('/home/log/radius.log', 'r') #file to operate on
    outfile = open('current_logs_sql_ready.txt', 'w')       #ending file, change name here to change the final file name
    error_count = 0
    time_count = 0

    for l in infile:                           #loops through each line in the file
        tokens = l.split()                      #counter

        if len(tokens) >19:                     #checks to make sure each line in valid in the .log file
            outfile.write(l.split()[+0] +'-') #Gets Day
            outfile.write(l.split()[+1] +'-') #Gets Month
            outfile.write(l.split()[+3] + ',')  # Gets Year
            outfile.write(l.split()[+2] + ',')  # Gets Time
            outfile.write(l.split()[-2] + ',')  # Gets Device
            outfile.write(l.split() [+9] + ',')  # Gets ID
            outfile.write(l.split()[+18] + ',')  # Gets AP
            outfile.write(l.split()[+19] + ',')  # Gets AP Group
            outfile.write(l.split()[+16] + '\n')  # Gets MAC
            time_count +=1


        else:                                      #this happens when a line in the file is invalid
            #outfile.write(l.split()[] + 'ERROR \n')  # Gets MAC
            print("Invalid Line \n")
            error_count +=1


    #print(error_count)
    #print('times ran =') +(time_count)


    infile.close()
    outfile.close()

text_org()    #runs the program
```

Essentially i'd like to use my parse program with the socket instead of a .txt file. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You have several options here.

The easiest is to simply take your existing `text_org` function and break out the "parse-a-single-line" part and put it in a separate function. Refactored, your code would look like:

```
def parse_line(outfile, line):
    tokens = line.split()
    outfile.write(...)
    ...

def text_org():
    ...
    with open('/home/log/radius.log', 'r') as infile:
        with open('current_logs_sql_ready.txt', 'w') as outfile:
            for l in infile:
                parse_line(outfile, l)
```

Then, from your socket handler:

```
log = socket.socket(socket.AF_UNIX, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
log.bind("/home/log/socket")

with open('current_logs_sql_ready.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    while True:
        line = log.recv(4096).decode()
        parse_line(outfile, line)
```

**If** the socket sender already delivers lines terminated by newlines, you can convert the socket directly into a python file-like object with `makefile` as Daniel Pryden's answer explains. (But the standard file object will expect to find "lines" and will keep attempting to read as long as it doesn't find the end-of-line character.)

If it does not provide newlines (as with, say, a standard syslog sender), you could create your own sub-class of socket that provides similar behavior with record-at-a-time iterator semantics:

```
class mysock(socket.socket):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    def __iter__(self):
        return self
    def __next__(self):
        return self.recv(4096).decode()

log = mysock(socket.AF_UNIX, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
log.bind("/home/log/socket")   

with open('current_logs_sql_ready.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    for line in log:
        parse_line(outfile, line)
```

Comment: The goal here was to prevent making a new text file, as soon as I got the lined parsed from the socket, I was going to immediately insert that into a db table. Is there anyway to do what I want just in a loop instead of just writing it to a new text file? Could I get the line in the socket, parse it without having to deal with an outfile?

Comment: Sure. Following the `tokens = line.split()` call, `tokens` is a list of "words". Do whatever you like with them in lieu of writing them to the file. In other words, you can simply change what `parse_line` does (pass it a DB connection instead of an output file, for example, and have it do an INSERT).

Comment: Thanks I think I understand. Last question is once I call the parse_line function, in my current program I do outfile.write(line.split()[+5], what can I replace outfile with? Would it be a good idea to initialize an array and have the function spit the splits out to the array and then insert the array into the DB? So for example could I do array = [] : then do array.write(line.split........) instead out outfile.write?

Comment: Yes. You need to learn your DB interface as a first step (and set up the DB). That will determine exactly how you do it. With `psycopg2` (a PostgreSQL interface library) for example, I'd do something like `db_cursor.execute('INSERT INTO mytable (x, y, z ...) VALUES (%s, %s, %s ...)', tokens)`. But you'll need to connect to the database and create the cursor first.